Semiconductor-graphene-semiconductor junction
In the literature, I've found Graphene-semiconductor junctions are treated as Schottky junctions. So by reverse-biasing a graphene n-semiconductor junction, we inject carriers into the graphene resulting in a fermi level shift.
How would this look like if I have a p-semiconductor graphene n-semiconductor junction under reverse bias? Would that just lead to electrons being injected from one side and holes from the other, cancelling each other out (so a net zero fermi level change in the graphene layer)?
From what I've read I think graphene would act as an almost transparent tunelling layer in such a sandwich. So would the depletion region width still increase with increasing reverse bias?

